# swift 3: func as argument

Tags: swift, parameters, func

I have several functions:

```
func x1(_ data: [Double], _ par1: Int, _ par2: Int) -> Double {
…
}

func x2(_ data: [Double], _ par1: Int, _ par2: Int, _ par3: Int) -> Double {
…
}
```

and I want to test them from `[-1 … 100]` as `par1, par2, …` so I have to call:

```
x1(data, -1, -1) 
x1(data, -1, 0)
...
x1(data, -1, 100)
x1(data, 0, -1)   
…
x1(data, 100, 100)
```

The same with

```
func x2(data, -1, -1, -1) … x2(data, 100, 100, 100)
```

Then compare results to find the largest among `x1` or `x2`. How can I code a func test that calls another func with unknown amount of parameters (x1 has 3, x2 has 4) and how do I call this test func?

```
func test(testfunc: (_ data: [Double], _ par: Int…) -> Double, _ data: [Double], params: [Int]…) -> [Int] {
    //?
    return *optimal parameters , for example: [10, 57]
}
```

Comment: you can create one function with 3rd `Int` to be an `Optional`, then make inside `if let` condition and just pass this function arguments (2 or 3)

Comment: As described, this isn't currently possible in Swift. It looks like you're looking for something similar to the "splat" operation that is discussed often (and was removed in SE-0029), but even with that, it's hard to imagine how your function could work. What if `params` were the wrong length? How could that be determined at *compile time*? (And it needs to be determined at compile time, or you open Pandora's box for selecting the right dispatch, not to mention basic type safety.) I think you need to approach another way.

Comment: Use Generics that is best option and along it use var param so that u can pass any no of param to it

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari, this has *nothing* whatsoever to do with generics. Perhaps you're thinking of `varargs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rob Napier stated, the only way to achieve type safety in testing is to have a test function for each `x*` function. However, if you can change your `x*` functions, there's a *much* simpler way: declare a *single* `x()` function that takes a variable number of arguments:

```
func x(_ data: [Double], _ pars: Int...) -> Double {
    // Loop through the variable number of pars like this:
    for index in pars { ... }
}
```

Now you can call this with *any* number of arguments, so:

```
let maxOf2 = x(data, -1, -1)
let maxOf7 = x(data, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)
```

And your test function will be equally simple:

```
func test(functionToTest: ([Double], Int...) -> (Double), data: [Double], pars: Int...) -> [Double] {
    return functionToTest(data, pars)
}
```

It may be a bit easier to read with a `typealias`:

```
typealias MaxFunction = ([Double], Int...) -> (Double)

func test(functionToTest: MaxFunction, data: [Double], pars: Int...) -> [Double] {
    return functionToTest(data, pars)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the solution to this! One more thing is how do I call func test? I try: var opt_par = test(x1, data, Array([-1 ... 100]) as! [Int], Array([-1 ... 100]) as! [Int]) - but that doesn't work.

Comment: Which part doesn't work? I can see a couple problems here. First, Swift doesn't (yet) auto-convert arrays into variable-length arguments, so you can't pass in `[-1 ..< 100]`; instead, you have to pass each array *element* in, like `test(x1, data, -1, 0, etc.)`. Second, the `test` method that I wrote expects *individual `Int`s* as the variable-length arguments, not *arrays* of `Int`s. Does that make sense?

Comment: The problem was with [-1 ... 100] as argument. I want test func to do all the stuff and give the result, so I wanted to pass array to it. I've changed it to: func test(functionToTest: MaxFunction, data: [Double], pars: **[Int]**...) -> [Double] { }. Now I pass Array(-1...100) and everything is fine. Thanks)

Answer (score -1):

I haven't fully understand your problem, but maybe thats a hint that your code is too complex. Try to split it into several tasks and test each of them alone.

A protocol based object oriented approach may look like that:

```
protocol OODouble {
    var value: Double { get }
}

final class ThreeParamDouble: OODouble {
    private let data: [Double]
    private let par1: Int
    private let par2: Int
    init(_ data: [Double], _ par1: Int, _ par2: Int) {
        self.data = data
        self.par1 = par1
        self.par2 = par2
    }
    var value: Double {
        get { /* calculate result (aka x1) here */ }
    }
}

final class FourParamDouble: OODouble {
    private let data: [Double]
    private let par1: Int
    private let par2: Int
    private let par3: Int
    init(_ data: [Double], _ par1: Int, _ par2: Int, _ par3: Int) {
        self.data = data
        self.par1 = par1
        self.par2 = par2
        self.par3 = par3
    }
    var value: Double {
        get { /* calculate result (aka x2) here */ }
    }
}

final class LargestDouble: OODouble {
    private let doubles: [OODouble]
    init(_ doubles: [OODouble]) {
        self.doubles = doubles
    }
    var value: Double {
        get {
            var largestDouble: Double = 0
            (doubles.map { $0.value }).forEach {
                largestDouble = largestDouble < $0 ? $0 : largestDouble
            }
            return largestDouble
        }
    }
}

let largestValue = LargestDouble([
    FourParamDouble(data, -1, -1, -1),
    ...
    FourParamDouble(data, 100, 100, 100)
])
let result = largestValue.value
```

Now you are able to test the calculation of x1 independent of the calculation x2 and even the 'find the largest one' ist testable independently. The last one can be testet with a fake protocol implementation:

```
final class OODoubleFake: OODouble {
    init(_ value: Double) {
        self.value = value
    }
    let value: Double
}
```

Comment: If you down vote someone you should tell him/her why.